# What does "Force" do in Uncrustify?

Tags: code-formatting, uncrustify

Many of the options include the `Force` value option:

> Add or remove space between nested parens
>
> `sp_paren_paren` { `Ignore`, `Add`, `Remove`, `Force` }

What does it mean? How is it different than `Add`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add means "add if not already present", meaning that if something's already there, leave it (and the formatting alone). Force means add if not present, and reformat if it is present:

```
// Original
if (cond)         {
    func();
}

// Add curly braces (already present, leaves formatting alone)
if (cond)         {
    func();
}

// Force curly braces
if (cond) {
    func();
}
```

Or another example:

```
// Original
if (cond)
    func();

// Add curly braces
if (cond) {
    func();
}

// Force curly braces (behaves just like add in this case)
if (cond) {
    func();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`Add` adds if it is not there.

`Remove` removes if it is there.

`Force` does a `remove` then an `add`.

Answer (score 3):

As "Add or remove X between A and B"

`Add`: only adds *a* X when there is no X appeared

```
AB -> AXB
AXB -> AXB
AXXB -> AXXB
```

`Remove`: removes all appeared X

```
AB -> AB
AXB -> AB
AXXB -> AB
```

`Force`: as edwinc said `Remove` then `Add` -> Removes all (any) X first and
        adds *a* X finally

```
AB -> AXB
AXB -> AB -> AXB
AXXB -> AB -> AXB
```

But sometimes 'add X' may be defined as add some number X elsewhere, so `Force` will like a "reformat" as Chris said.